# What does the "max_keys" key refer to in Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

While using the `paperclip` plugin on Rails, I've noticed the `max_keys` default of 1000.  **What does this actually refer to?**  I certainly have more than 1000 files to store in this one particular instance and I further do not want to do some messy things with folder organization for future manual searching.

Could someone clarify it's significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an S3 bucket parameter that sets the maximum number of keys in the HTTP response body.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html